# Spilt a bit of water on my keyboard

Tags: laptop, laptop-repair

Alright so i spilt a bit of water on my keyboard while back. It was very little so i didn't really try to do anything. However a few minutes later i realised that some of the keys on my keyboard won't working very well. So I switched the laptop off and kept it upside down. I turned it on after half an hour and although things have improved, I'm very  concerned... 
For example, the A key doesn't work. Pressing 1 or 2 types out both etc.

Rest everything seems to work as usual.

Do I need to do anything except wait this out?

Comment: When water comes in contact with electrical components it can cause corrosion and damage, since it conducts electricity. You may need to get a new keyboard...

Answer (score 0):

Shake the water off well with the laptop upside down (turn it off first so the HD heads are parked, if it's a magnetic disk). If you have a hair dryer, you can blow it in a low temperature. Wait for a few hours for it to dry. Then see if you still have problems. If you do, it's time to turn to a technician.